# How can I control the hunger bar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there anyway that I can use commands to increase, decrease a players hunger when they have a certain amount of hunger bar, and testfor player's hunger bar in vanilla Minecraft?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @TheVoidChaos Who? Me?

Comment: No, someone else did for some odd reason.

Comment: Ohh, I see, I voted up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
/testfor @a {foodLevel:20}
```

> 20 is full hunger points and 0 is no hunger points... as for setting a hunger amount without the ability to change NBT with players yet there isn't an easy way to do this, you would need to give them the effect of hunger for a set amount of time to get them to the correct level and then to increase it give them a saturation effect for the exact amount of time to get them to the correct level....lots of work and a lot of command blocks.

Credit:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2182343-how-to-control-a-players-hunger

Comment: Cool! Don't forget to click on the link for some different methods and discussions!

Comment: The /testfor command is only available for Bedrock edition